# new, shared pointer & virtual functions

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, virtual-functions

In my program I'm facing another difficulty (I store them all and ask many problems in a burts :P). What I do have is a functor - those functors ae all inherited from `DuplicateFn` - which has a virtual operator() and each child is expected to write it's version of that.

Now one of the childs - called merge - may not succeed, in which case it should try a fallback method. Currently that class thus looks like:

```
class MergeFn : public DuplicateFn {
public:
    MergeFn() : FallBack(new SkipFn())
    {
    }
    MergeFn(GMProject const* Out, GMProject const* In, DuplicateFn* f) 
        : DuplicateFn(Out, In), FallBack(f)
    {
    }
    virtual void operator() (GMProject::pTree& tOut, const GMProject::pTree& tIn) const {
        if (!GMProject::isMergeable(tOut.GetName())) {
            (*FallBack)(tOut, tIn); //virtual table resolves this to the correct class
        } else {
        }
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<DuplicateFn> FallBack;
};
```

I think the problem is clearly visible already here - In the non-default constructor, this method seizes ownership of the given parameter. - This is not what I want: it should copy that parameter and keep ownership of that.
Now  I tried `, FallBack(new DuplicateFn(f))` However this won't work either - as now there is a compile error that it tries to instantiate an object from a class with pure virtual methods.

So how can I do this? - Do I have to specify a specific constructor for each type? - Just to copy it corectly? Or do I have to go through RTTI? I hope there's a better approach than those 2.

**edit**
To show how mergeFn gets initialized (and used):

```
std::unique_ptr<detail::DuplicateFn> foo;
foo.reset(new detail::MergeFn(this, &Other, DuplicateFns.at(HandleDuplicate)));
```

DuplicateFns is a map which helps converting user inputs (string) towards function-pointers. - Or as it is now, pointers to objects of a subtype from DuplicateFn (pointer type is DuplicateFn* )

This is then used as a call-back method

```
ProjectTree.combine_if(tree, &SimilarTreeValue, foo.get());
```

Which combines 2 trees into one - when SimilarTreeValue returns true, the entry is considered a duplicate. If the entry is a leaf the 3rd parameter is called - the functor we're talking about :).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (in my view) is to change the signature of the constructor to require a shared pointer already:

```
MergeFn(GMProject const * Out,
        GMProject const * In,
        std::shared_ptr<DuplicateFn> f) /* ... */
```

The second option is to endow your entire class hierarchy with `clone()` functions:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual Base * clone() const { return new Base(*this); }
};

struct Der1 : Base
{
  virtual Der1 * clone() const { return new Der1(*this); }
};
```

Then you can initialize `FallBack(f->clone())`.

Personally I'd go with the first version, and I'd also check whether it isn't feasible to replace the shared pointer by a unique pointer.

Comment: @curiousguy: `unique_ptr` is a much lighter-weight (no dynamic allocation, no virtual dispatch). Only use `shared_ptr` if you really have to *share* ownership.

Comment: "_Only use shared_ptr if you really have to share ownership._" I see at least two owners here: the caller and the callee. A function argument of type `unique_ptr` implies a transfer of ownership. What if the caller still wants ownership?

Comment: Which caller? We don't know that. All I can see is the constructor argument. It's entirely possible that only one single owner is required. Anyway, only the OP can decide that, since we don't know anything about the context.

Comment: @KerrekSB hmm, but I really need to "transfer" ownership - or at least I need to be sure the outside world can't touch the pointer. However at the same time, the outside world shouldn't be changed by this class either.

Comment: @paul23: You can do all that with a unique pointer, I believe. It's impossible to tell without context -- could you post a small, representative example of how you intend to use the class?

Answer (score 0):

> `new DuplicateFn(f)`

that will only slice the functor `f`.

You need a clone function:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>

template <class T>
// runtime checked clone function
// T::do_clone() must be accessible to checked_clone
T *checked_clone (const T* that) {
    T *p = that->do_clone();
    assert (typeid (*p) == typeid (*that));
    return p;
}

// clone for an abstract class
#define IMPLEMENT_CLONE_ABSTRACT(Class) \
    friend Class *checked_clone<Class> (const Class* that); \
 \
public: \
    Class *clone_naked() const { \
        return checked_clone (this); \
    } \
    unique_ptr<Class> clone_unique() const { \
        return unique_ptr<Class> (checked_clone (this)); \
    } \     \
private: \
    virtual Class *do_clone() const = 0; \
/* end of IMPLEMENT_CLONE_ABSTRACT */

class Base {
    IMPLEMENT_CLONE_ABSTRACT(Base)
};

// clone for a concrete class
#define IMPLEMENT_CLONE_CONCRETE(Class) \
    friend Class *checked_clone<Class> (const Class* that); \
 \
public: \
    Class *clone_naked() const { \
        return checked_clone (this); \
    } \
    unique_ptr<Class> clone_unique() const { \
        return unique_ptr<Class> (checked_clone (this)); \
    } \     \
 \
private: \
    virtual Class *do_clone() const {  \
        return new Class (*this); \
    } \
/* end of IMPLEMENT_CLONE_CONCRETE */

class Derived : public Base {
    IMPLEMENT_CLONE_CONCRETE(Derived)
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the constructor of shared_ptr which takes a custom destructor and pass an empty function for it.  So for example.

```
void dontDelete(DuplicateFn *pFn ) {
  // Do nothing!
  }

class MergeFn : public DuplicateFn { 
public: 
    MergeFn() : FallBack(new SkipFn()) 
    { 
    }

    MergeFn(GMProject const* Out, GMProject const* In, DuplicateFn* f)  
        : DuplicateFn(Out, In), FallBack(f, dontDelete) 
    { 
    }

    virtual void operator() (GMProject::pTree& tOut, const GMProject::pTree& tIn) const { 
        if (!GMProject::isMergeable(tOut.GetName())) { 
            (*FallBack)(tOut, tIn); //virtual table resolves this to the correct class 
        } else { 
        } 
    }

private: 
    std::shared_ptr<DuplicateFn> FallBack; 
};
```

Comment: "_You can use the constructor of shared_ptr which takes a custom destructor and pass an empty function for it._" whenever I read this, I think "trying to get out of a design problem with a cheap trick will not do it". This is yet another example of that.